# How to fix type qualifiers errors in classes?

Tags: c++

This is my main.cpp code. The input is 3 strings and the output Prints out the value and length of the 3 String objects passed to it

```
void Display(const String &str1, const String &str2, const String &str3)
{
  cout << "str1 holds \"";
  str1.print(); // the error is here about the str1
  cout.flush();
  cout << "\" (length = " << str1.length() << ")" << endl;

  cout << "str2 holds \"";
  str2.print();
  cout.flush();
  cout << "\" (length = " << str2.length() << ")" << endl;

  cout << "str3 holds \"";
  str3.print();
  cout.flush();
  cout << "\" (length = " << str3.length() << ")" << endl;
}
```

This is the error:

Error C2662: 'String::print' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const String' to 'String &'

This is in my implementation file file: Did I do something wrong here?

```
void String::print()
{
cout << m_pName << ": ";
cout << (int)m_str1 << ", ";
cout << (int)m_str2 << ", ";
cout << (int)m_str3 << endl;
}
```

Comment: Make `print()` a `const`-qualified member function: `void print() const`

Comment: `(int)m_str1` looks **very** dodgy. At the very least use a C++-style cast and change the variable name to something meaningful.

Comment: there's a rule in programming called DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself, your code offends it quite badly. make display handle one string at a time and you'll save yourself modifying same thing three times(or modifying it once, forgetting about other two and wondering why the heck it doesn't work...)

Comment: @aryjczyk I've never heard of this "Dry rule". Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

`str1` is a reference to a ***`const`*** `String`.

In simple words, compiler wants to make sure `str1.print()` will not modify the `str1`.

Therefore, it looks for a `const` overload of `print` method which doesn't exist.

Make the `print` method `const`:

```
class String
{
   ...

   void print() const;
                ^^^^^^
   ...
};


void String::print() const
{                    ^^^^^
...
}
```